# _tkinter.TclError: format error in bitmap data

Tags: python, tkinter, bitmapimage

This line:

```
bitmap = Tkinter.BitmapImage(file="logo.bmp")
```

Gives me this error:

```
  File "gpm.py", line 314, in <module>
    bitmap = Tkinter.BitmapImage(file=LOGO_PATH)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3365, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'bitmap', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3262, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: format error in bitmap data
```

I have no clue how to fix this. It doesn't work with any .bmp file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tkinter BitmapImage takes an [X11 bitmap file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_BitMap) as an argument. This is *not* the same format as a windows .bmp file. Make sure you're using the correct type of file. Typically, the suffix of an X11 bitmap file is `.xbm`.